# What does the argument of function rgamma in R mean?

Tags: python, r

My advisor asked me to transfer the R code `A = rgamma(n = 400, 24, 4)` into python. I thought numpy.random.gamma would make sense. But sadly I don't know the corresponding argument of numpy.random.gamma.

Comment: `numpy.random.gamma(size=400, shape=24, scale=1/4)`

Comment: you can see the arguments and parametrisations using the docs, [`rgamma`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/GammaDist.html) and [`numpy.random.gamma`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.gamma.html)